# What is/are the best thing(s) I can do to make my WordPress blog more popular?

Tags: seo

What are the best things that I can do to get my Wordpress blog out there? What are good plugins that I can use to get listed in Googles search? Is there anything/anywhere else I can register my Wordpress blog to attract more visitors?

Comment: Even though your blog is powered by WordPress, this is a question regarding SEO/SEM and not WP administration or development ... I vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: But I did ask what plugins can help for such question :S

Comment: You did, but for such a generic question you'd be better served searching the WordPress plugin repository for the term SEO: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=seo

Comment: Maybe you could ask for general SEO tips on [the Pro Webmasters site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), and then come back with specific ideas and ask how to implement them with WordPress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide content that people crave to find, consume and share.

There is no technical solution to make site popular. If there was one - everyone would use it and field will be leveled again.

There are a lot of minor tweaks to implement (heading structure, social buttons, etc), but none of those will automagically bring in traffic and none of those work exactly same across different blogs with different content.

The best you can do on technical side is too keep an eye that your blog is reasonably fast and markup makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

New bloggers always wonder how to start , and what content to post in their blog the best advice i can offer is to follow Google and search engine trends just type it in google and you find the hottest topics in the internet post about them and make sure you have good social profile google plus circles and twitter user and facebook followers to 100x your traffic